# MongoDB using Mongoose save issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some issues saving datas in my mongodb using mongoose. Here is the code that i use :

```
////////////////////////////////////////
//// Mongoose test
var url = mongoUrl + dbCollectionName;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(url);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
    console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connected to Mongo with Mongoose');
    insertDocuments(db);
});

var ackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hostgroup : String,
    host : String,
    service : String,
    timePeriod : String,
    startTime : Number,
    ackTime : Number,
    deltaTime : Number,
    caseNumb : String,
    state : Number,
    author : String,
    ackId : Number,
    });

// Creation of the model document
var ackModel = mongoose.model(collectionName, ackSchema, collectionName);

//////////////////////////////////////
//// Functions

// MySQL function (query, push to array etc)
var mysqlQuery = function (callback) {
    var query = mysqlConnection.query(sqlQuery), sql = [];
    var anyRow = 0;
    // Log query error
    query.on('error', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(getTimeStamp() + 'Error in MySQL query: ' + err);
            return;
        }
    });

    // On result, push results in sql array
    query.on('result', function (row) {
        // Non-blocking I/O
        mysqlConnection.pause();
        mysqlConnection.resume();
        sql.push(row);
        callback(row);
    });

    // Information then close connection
    query.on('end', function (row) {
        // If anRow == 1, close the app.
        if (!row) { anyRow = 1; }
        if (row) { anyRow = 0; }

        if (anyRow == 1) {
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to Mongoose closed ');
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MySQL closed ');
            process.exit(0);
        }
        if (anyRow == 0) {
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to Mongoose closed ');
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MySQL closed ');
        }
    });
    mysqlConnection.end();
};               

// Insert Documents into mongodb using MySQL info and mongoose ackModel.
var insertDocuments = function(db) {
    // SQL Query to fetch row
    mysqlQuery(function (row) {
        //// IF 8/20
        if (row.timeperiod == timePeriod820) {
            returnValue = timePeriodCalc(row); // Function from timeperiod.js
            deltaValue = parseInt(returnValue.slice(6)); // Get our Delta Value
            caseValue = returnValue.slice(0,4); // Get the Case Number, verification purpose
        //// ELSE 24/7
        } else {
            deltaValue = (row.ack_time - row.start_time);
            caseValue = 'C.0';};
        };

        var ack = new ackModel({
            hostgroup : row.hostgroup,
            host : row.hostname,
            service : row.servicename,
            timePeriod : row.timeperiod,
            startTime : row.start_time,
            ackTime : row.ack_time,
            state : row.state,
            deltaTime : deltaValue,
            caseNumb : caseValue,
            author : row.author,
            ackId : row.ack_id});

        console.log(ack);       
        //console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'SAVE Mongoose : ' + ack.author + ' ' + ack.ackId);

        ack.save(function (err1, ack) {
            if (err1) {
                console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Mongoose .save error : ' + err1);
            }
            else { 
                console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'SAVE Mongoose : ' + ack.author + ' ' + ack.ackId); 
            }
        });
    }); 
};
```

This is what the log return :

```
[2016-01-12 10:56:04.403] - Connected to Mongo with Mongoose
{ _id: 5694cdb49b274b1100262896,
  ackId: 1184,
  author: 'victor.b',
  caseNumb: 'C.10',
  deltaTime: -1200,
  state: 2,
  ackTime: 1452590840,
  startTime: 1452592040,
  timePeriod: 'RESSOURCES-GPE-N1-8/20',
  service: 'Service-Random-5M',
  host: 'CRI_HOST3',
  hostgroup: 'CRIDF' }
[2016-01-12 10:56:04.506] - Connection to Mongoose closed
[2016-01-12 10:56:04.507] - Connection to MySQL closed
```

So as you can see everything seems to be fine since my ack document from my ackModel is filled perfectly with the right informations. But the save didn't work. I've tested a LOT of thing before coming here but i'm out of ideas.

EDIT 1 : Thanks to @zangw i've figured out that my problem is coming from this block of the code :

```
// On result, push results in sql array
query.on('result', function (row) {
    // Non-blocking I/O
    mysqlConnection.pause();
    mysqlConnection.resume();
    sql.push(row);
    callback(row);
});
```

Since i'm not tottally used with node.js callbacks maybe i'm doing something wrong with the one in there.

Comment: I just test it based your codes, and get the result `SAVE Mongoose : victor.b 1184`, here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/richzw/827054124f8b6b0282a4), I just delete the `mysqlQuery` and `getTimeStamp()`, because I am not clear them...

Comment: Have you check whether this `ack` is saved into mongoDB or not?

Comment: Yes of course, the ack should be saved into my col_201601 but the collection is not created : [Screenshoot](http://puu.sh/msSFM/4b23d4f495.png)

Comment: @zangw Started from the code you used i've added codes trying and logging at each step and it appears that my problem come from the query.on('result' ... ) block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was from this part :

```
    query.on('end', function (row) {
    // If anRow == 1, close the app.
    if (!row) { anyRow = 1; }
    if (row) { anyRow = 0; }
    if (anyRow == 1) {
        console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MongoDB closed ');
        console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MySQL closed ');
        process.exit(0);
    }
    if (anyRow == 0) {
        console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MongoDB closed ');
        console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MySQL closed ');
    }
});
```

So i've stopped usinf stream reading rows and changing the MySQLQuery and inserdocuments function into one simpler function :

```
var insertDocuments = function() {
// Get the documents collection
var returnValue = 0,
    caseValue = "";
var test = 0;
var ackAllreadyExist = 0;

//var query = mysqlConnection.query(sqlQuery), sql = [];
var query = mysqlConnection.query(sqlQuery, function(err,row) {
    if(err) console.log('MySQL error : ' + err);
    for (var i=0; i<row.length; i++){
        //// IF 8/20
        if (row[i].timeperiod == timePeriod820) {
            returnValue = timePeriodCalc(row[i]); // Function from timeperiod.js
            deltaValue = parseInt(returnValue.slice(6)); // Get our Delta Value
            caseValue = returnValue.slice(0,4); // Get the Case Number, verification purpose
        //// ELSE 24/7
        } else {
            deltaValue = (row[i].ack_time - row[i].start_time);
            caseValue = 'C.0';
        };

        var ack = new ackModel({
            hostgroup : row[i].hostgroup,
            host : row[i].hostname,
            service : row[i].servicename,
            timePeriod : row[i].timeperiod,
            startTime : row[i].start_time,
            ackTime : row[i].ack_time,
            state : row[i].state,
            deltaTime : deltaValue,
            caseNumb : caseValue,
            author : row[i].author,
            ackId : row[i].ack_id});

        //console.log(row[i]);
        //console.log(ack);     
        //console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'SAVE Mongoose : ' + ack.author + ' ' + ack.ackId);

        ack.save(function (err,ack) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Mongoose .save error : ' + err);
            };
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'SAVE Mongoose : ' + ack.author + ' ' + ack.ackId); 
            test++;
            if(test == row.length) {
                mysqlConnection.end();
                console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MongoDB closed ');
                console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'Connection to MySQL closed ');
                process.exit(0);
            };
        });
        if (debug == 1) { 
            console.log(getTimeStamp() + 'SAVE Mongoose : ' + ack.author + ' ' + ack.ackId); 
        };
    };
});
};
```

I'm not supposing to work like this in node.js i know but after 2 week on this problem (It's for my work, money !) I don't mind anymore.

Thanks @zangw for showing me the start of the answer.